# Need C# Regex to get pairs of words in a sentence

Tags: c#, regex

Is there a regex that would take the following sentence:

"I want this split up into pairs"

and generate the following list:

"I want",
"want this",
"this split",
"split up",
"up into",
"into pairs"

Comment: What if it's an odd number of words?

Comment: @Qtax that doesn't matter, as every word is in a pair with one or two neighbors.

Comment: My bad, didn't look at the wanted result properly.

Comment: Yes, needs to be regex since it is an already implemented system that uses regex for everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since words need to be re-used, you need lookahead assertions :

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"(     # Match and capture in backreference no. 1:
     \w+    # one or more alphanumeric characters
     \s+    # one or more whitespace characters.
    )       # End of capturing group 1.
    (?=     # Assert that there follows...
     (\w+)  # another word; capture that into backref 2.
    )       # End of lookahead.", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Groups[1].Value + matchResult.Groups[2].Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

For groups of threes:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"(     # Match and capture in backreference no. 1:
     \w+    # one or more alphanumeric characters
     \s+    # one or more whitespace characters.
    )       # End of capturing group 1.
    (?=     # Assert that there follows...
     (      # and capture...
      \w+   # another word,
      \s+   # whitespace,
      \w+   # word.
     )      # End of capturing group 2.
    )       # End of lookahead.", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

etc.

Comment: Lookaheads don't capture do they?

Comment: @Renesis, @David Amey: Not by themselves, but I put a capturing group into the lookahead assertion, didn't you notice that? I've just made it a little clearer by changing it into a verbose regex.

Comment: @Tim That was not there at the time I made my comment :)

Comment: I strip out punctuations with another regex so no need to worry about them

Comment: Awesome! Worked perfectly! Can this be extended to groups of 3's?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! You definitely are a Regex master!

Comment: I removed my downvote since the fix was made after I voted.  However, I *don't get the upvotes*, since this still needs post-processing to produce the desired result.  So it's not really a "regex" solution to this problem, and so it's not really better in any way (and a bit more confusing) than the other solutions using `Split`.

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```
var myWords = myString.Split(' ');

var myPairs = myWords.Take(myWords.Length - 1)
    .Select((w, i) => w + " " + myWords[i + 1]);
```

Comment: @Tim I stand corrected, I still hold my way is more efficient assuming he only needs to split by spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You're could just use `string.Split()` and combine the results:

```
var words = myString.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
var pairs = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
{
    pairs.Add(words[i] + words[i+1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it only with RegEx and without post-processing, we can re-use Tim Pietzcker's answer but passing two consecutive RegEx

We can pass the original from Tim Pietzcker's answer and the same with a lookbehind that will make the regex to start capturing from the second word.

If you combine the results from the two RegEx you will have all the pairs from the text.

```
Regex regexObj1 = new Regex(
    @"(     # Match and capture in backreference no. 1:
     \w+    # one or more alphanumeric characters
     \s+    # one or more whitespace characters.
    )       # End of capturing group 1.
    (?=     # Assert that there follows...
     (\w+)  # another word; capture that into backref 2.
    )       # End of lookahead.", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Groups[1].Value + matchResult.Groups[2].Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}

Regex regexObj2 = new Regex(
    @"(?<=  # Assert that there preceds and will not be captured
     \w+\s+ # the first word followed by any space
    )
    (     # Match and capture in backreference no. 1:
     \w+    # one or more alphanumeric characters
     \s+    # one or more whitespace characters.
    )       # End of capturing group 1.
    (?=     # Assert that there follows...
     (\w+)  # another word; capture that into backref 2.
    )       # End of lookahead.", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
Match matchResult1 = regexObj1.Match(subjectString);
Match matchResult2 = regexObj2.Match(subjectString);
```

etc

For groups of threes:

You will need to add a third RegEx to the program:

```
Regex regexObj3 = new Regex(
        @"(?<=  # Assert that there preceds and will not be captured
         \w+\s+\w+\s+ # the first and second word followed by any space
        )
        (     # Match and capture in backreference no. 1:
         \w+    # one or more alphanumeric characters
         \s+    # one or more whitespace characters.
        )       # End of capturing group 1.
        (?=     # Assert that there follows...
         (\w+)  # another word; capture that into backref 2.
        )       # End of lookahead.", 
        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
    Match matchResult1 = regexObj1.Match(subjectString);
    Match matchResult2 = regexObj2.Match(subjectString);
    Match matchResult3 = regexObj3.Match(subjectString);
```